# Define packages that will be installed in all new conda environments

Tags: python, conda

I would like to be able to define a list of standard packages that should be installed on all my conda environments. E.g. when I create a new environment, I know that I will always need jupyterlab, numpy, matplotlib, pandas, ... and it would be great if I didn't have to install those on each new environment that I create.

Is there anyway that this is possible? I didn't find anything in the docs or elsewhere on the internet, but maybe I've missed something...

#### Example

Now, when I create a new environment, I have to manually specify which packages I need in that environment. So each time that I create a new environment, I have to

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab numpy matplotlib pandas <and a bunch of other packages>
```

This is very tedious, since there are a lot of packages that I need.

#### Current workaround

I currently have a shell script in my home directory which does this work, so if I create a new environment, I just have to run this script. However, it would be great if I could just tell conda to install those packages automatically on all my new environments.

Comment: you can create a yml file with the packages names in the text format, when creating the new environments. https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#export the current environment to yml file (txt file)
conda env export > environment.yml 
# this will create new environment with all packages same as previous environment
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

Comment: Yes, but then I will have to create a yml file for every environment that I make, which is not what I'm looking for

Comment: You can create yml file that consists of all packages required and use it whenever you need to create a new environment with the packages-.

Comment: Hmm, okay, and can I make this yml file without specifying the name of the environment, such that I can use the `-n <env-name>` option?

Comment: Yes. You can. You can also use pip install from a list of package in a txt file. e.g. pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: @wohe1 It's worth mentioning that you can build the `environment.yml` file manually.